# Passport local strategy done callback does not pass error json message

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to pass a JSON message when authentication fails, using done callback in the LocalStrategy, but all I get is 401 and "Unauthorized" string in the response.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
});

var strategy = new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
    function (email, password, done) {
        if (email === 'test@gmail.com' && password === 'pass') {
            return done(null, { email: 'test@gmail.com' });
        } else {
            // never get this json object on the client side when posting invalid credentials
            return done(null, false, { message: 'invalid email or password' });
        }
    }
);

passport.use(strategy);

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    res.json(req.user);
});


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hello!' });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('api is listening on ', server.address().port);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "passport_example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `message` value you are setting is stored in session and flash. I don't think passport has any option to send json error message. But you can pass a callback in `authenticate` method and send message from there:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next ){
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err) }
      if (!user) { return res.json( { message: info.message }) }
      res.json(user);
    })(req, res, next);   
});
```

Comment: Use 'res.status(403).json(info)' to properly respond with unauthorized status. Also, you will need to call 'req.logIn(user, function(err) { next(err) };' in order to actually log the user in.

Comment: Sorry, 401 Unauthorized is the correct status code.

Comment: Is there no a way without using closures?